# How to Extend Django DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS Setting

Tags: django, settings

The Django setting DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS has a [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats) that consists of a tuple with several input formats. I would like to put a setting in my settings file that keeps all those default formats and adds one more.

I tried:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p', )
```

But it seems to over-write the defaults. I realize I could just copy the defaults from the docs and create a new tuple. But that seems ugly.

Any one know how to do this?

Comment: Does this work? `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS + ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p', )`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from django.conf.global_settings import DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p',)
```

I believe this should work in your settings.py file.